# How do I correct the code in php?

Tags: php, functions

I am new to PHP and I'm unable to solve the code. It's showing an error.

```
<?php 

function thumbImg() {
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       the_post_thumbnail( array(54,54) );
   } else {
       <img src='<?php echo $data['featured_img']; ?>' alt='<?php the_title(); ?>' /> 
   }
} 

?>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that set a fallback image for a recent post widget if there is no featured image set, so I am trying to make a function/shortcode I can use in the my recent post widget page `['featured_img']` which will get data from admin panel.

Comment: You need to close php tag before start to show html or put html code inside a string and use echo. This is basic php. (look at your else statement)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing html and php content. You should write it like this:

```
<?php 

function thumbImg() {
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       the_post_thumbnail( array(54,54) );
   } else {
       echo "<img src='{$data['featured_img']}' alt='".get_the_title()."' />";
   }
} 

?>
```

This way, you don't need to open and close again the php tag.

Comment: should use `get_the_title()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the PHP tag before you write html code for image source and then reopen the PHP tag once your HTML is finished.

```
    <?php 

function thumbImg() {
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       the_post_thumbnail( array(54,54) );
   } else {
    ?>
       <img src='<?php echo $data['featured_img']; ?>' alt='<?php the_title(); ?>' />
       <?php
   }
} 

?>
```